# Questions around calculation of time complexity of an algorithm

Tags: big-o, algorithm-analysis

I am a newbie to algorithms. One thing that i always get confused is about calculation of algorithm runtimes. 
For example: The following piece of code in Python

```
for i in range(n):
    #O(?)
    i*=k
```

What is the runtime of the above for loop?
The answer that has been provided to me is: O(log n to the base k).

I am finding it difficult to understand as to how this runtime was arrived at.

Any hep would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that that runtime cannot possibly be correct. The loop body is executed n times, and every time it is doing work, so clearly it *must* be *more than* O(n).

Comment: The other problem with the provided answer is that O() notation ignores constant factors, so the base for the logarithm doesn't matter.  It should be O(log n), except that, as @JörgWMittag said, if you're doing anything n times then the complexity can't be smaller than O(n).

Comment: @DavidThornley: Well, you can certainly be more precise. There's nothing wrong with O(log_k n), it's just that O(log_k n) == O(log_10 n) == O(log_2 n) == O(log n) == O(23 log_42 n + 85).

Answer (score 0):

The runtime of an algorithm is often expressed as a function of its complexity. In your example, you can think of "runtime" as "the number of steps". The complexity is `O( log( n, k ) )`, according to your source.

When `n` is `20` and `k` is `3`, how much is `log( n, k )`? It should be `log( 20, 3 )` which is about `2.72`.

How many steps does your algorithm take? If you print out your values on each loop you should see something like:

```
i = 0, i*k = 0
i = 1, i*k = 3
i = 4, i*k = 12
i = 13, i*k = 39
```

So, it took four steps to perform the algorithm. Clearly there is a disagreement between 3 (rounded up from 2.72) and 4.

Looking at your statement of the algorithm, I suspect that the Python code should have been stated as follows:

```
k = 3
n = 20
i = 1
while i <= n:
  print "i =", i, "i*k =", i*k
  i = i*k
  i = i+1
```

This algorithm will show only three steps, matching the estimated complexity.

You should note that your original statement of the Python code is **wrong** because it is modifying the iteration control variable, `i`, in the middle of the loop. Such practices will lead to confusion and errors and are strongly discouraged.

Comment: `i` is *not* the iteration control variable. It is the element variable. `for`/`in` in Python is a `foreach` iterator, not a C-style `for` (which is essentially a `while`) loop. There will always be `n` iterations of the loop, no matter what you do to `i`. When `n` is `20` and `k` is `3`, there should be 20 iterations of the loop, each with a multiplication which takes log(i) time (i.e. number of digits / bits). I believe, there are actually faster multiplication algorithms, but I don't think Python is using them. The lower bound for multiplication is still unknown.

Comment: The runtime is circa SUM(log i, from 1 to n), which is more than n and less than n * log n.

Comment: Sorry, that should be SUM((log i)^2, from 1 to n), of course, which is more than n and less than n * (log n)^2.